# What are the best sites/books for learning Apache?

Tags: apache

What are the best sites/books for learning Apache from scratch? 
Any recommendations?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/tutorials.html is a list of different topics with corresponding tutorials. It is the apache project´s own recommendations, so I would start there with the topic I would want to understand and the go on to the next subject as more and more questions arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these books 
Apache: The Definitive Guide, Third Edition
Apache Cookbook, Second Edition

The whole list is available here 
http://www.apachebookstore.com/confluence/oss/display/BOOKS/Books+on+Apache+HTTP+Server+(httpd)

Comment: I also found that list, but how do you know that those are in fact the best ones?

Answer (score 5):

The official Documentation is a good place to start.

Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/ and http://httpd.apache.org/docs-project/

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching Apache books for programmers and selected to read this:

Apache Cookbook, Second Edition - Solutions and Examples for Apache Administration
     - By Rich Bowen, Ken Coar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) to be very useful. It has a lot of examples which make understanding Apache and its uses easier.